# Pause or stop Instagram embed video after scrolling away

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, instagram, embed

I'm embedding videos from Instagram in my website using below URL:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/Bp4I3hRhd_v/embed
```

Embedding it with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bp4I3hRhd_v/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" width="450" height="450"></iframe>
```

Is there any way to stop playing this video when it is no more on screen (or user has already scrolled away from it)?

PS. I have already tried all the solutions given on internet for youtube videos but it doesn't work for Instagram videos because Insta videos has different embedding pattern then YT ones.

Answer (score -1):

use the below URL's for your job

[how can I pause a youtube embed when a user scrolls away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150423/how-can-i-pause-a-youtube-embed-when-a-user-scrolls-away)
(or)

https://fjorgedigital.com/insights/blog/play-youtube-videos-on-scroll-over/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not embedding youtube videos, they are instagram videos. It embeds in a different way than youtube ones, hence I cannot have this object YT.Player to controller Insta videos.

Comment: Is it stop is working on clicking of the video. If that works write a method which makes click on that area automatically through the code while scrolling the screen. This is the one option to forcefully stop or start something.

Comment: We cannot do cross origin operations within iFrames.