# How can I pause a video when scrolling down in ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I scroll down the video should stop.

I tried a few things from internet but didn't worked. I tried

1. [how can I pause a youtube embed when a user scrolls away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150423/how-can-i-pause-a-youtube-embed-when-a-user-scrolls-away)
2. [How to play and pause a Youtube video in a webpage while scrolling(using javascript or jquery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381043/how-to-play-and-pause-a-youtube-video-in-a-webpage-while-scrollingusing-javascr)
3. [Autoplay Youtube Video When Scrolled to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111919/autoplay-youtube-video-when-scrolled-to)

**It would be a great help if someone can share a good resource of ANGULAR**

THIS IS THE CODE FOR HTML I AM GETTING FROM DB

```
     <div class="ast-oembed-container">
       <iframe title="Genetics - &#039;s preparation Program" 
         width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J3CGg1NmA?feature=oembed"
         frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media;
         gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
```